# How to pass variables from angular controller to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have two html divs, each having a bunch of input fields. I also have an angular controller that gets the data entered in the input fields and checks if they are valid (ie: email, passwords match, etc). What I'm trying to do is hide the first div and show the second one once the controller says that the text entered in the first div is valid. Here is what the html looks like:

```
  <div id = "stageOne">
  <!-- whole bunch of inputs here -->
 </div>

<a class = "btn" id = "stageOneDone" ng-click = "checkFields(true)">Continue</a>
  <!-- First stage ends here-->


  <div align = "center" id = "stageTwo" style = "display: none">
     <!-- whole bunch of inputs here -->
  </div>

  <script>

  $(function(){

      $('#stageOneDone').click(function(){

        //var completedIncorrectly = something

        if(!completedIncorrectly){
          $('#stageOne').hide();
          $('#stageTwo').show();
        }

      })


  });

  </script>
```

The function checkFields() expects the value true when it should check the values of the first div and false for the second div. What I can't figure out how to do is get the return value of the function and use it in jquery.

EDIT: If you're thinking why not just show/hide the divs using angular, I want to use jquery's animations.

Comment: you should create a directive to do this, so that you can pass data from your controller and manipulate the dom correctly, it is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this problem by just writing all the jquery in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can set variable inside controller, like $scope.step = 'one';

```
<div ng-show="step='one'">first step</div>
<div ng-show="step='second'">second step</div>
...
```

You don't need jQuery to do this.

Comment: Check my edit. I'm trying to use jquery's animations. All I need to know how to do is define a variable outside jquery that I can use inside it.

Comment: so just define global variable somewhere and set it and get it. Anyway you can use jquery animations inside checkFields(), but better to use css animations and ng-class

Comment: How can I define a global variable in angular and access it in jquery? That's basically my question! :)

Comment: var completedIncorrectly = true; 
before $(function(){ ... and its done

Comment: Why would it be = true? I'm trying to get the value from the angular controller..

Comment: by default incorrectly is true; then set to false (without var) inside your controller.

Comment: That doesn't work. All of this has to happen when a button is clicked, which calls a function inside the controller and that function returns a value which I have to see inside jquery. I cant change the value in the controller because $scope.completedIncorrectly = false doesnt change the value in the script tag.

Comment: without scope, you have set it inside your controller

Comment: The controller is in a different file. If I just write `completedIncorrectly = false` in the controller file (without var) its going to give me an error. If I write var then its going to define a completely new variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122045/discussion-between-artem-gorlachev-and-swailem95).

Comment: You shouldn't mix jQuery with angular. Measure up your project, if you've been working with jQuery, to add angular for small features would be an overkill. If you've been developing in angular, then try to use ng-animate or similar directives instead of adding jQuery code for a couple of animations